# detach scroll bar from scrollable div and position it elsewhere on the page with css

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a div that takes up the left half of my page that has an `overflow-y: scroll`.  I would like for the scrollbar for that div to be positioned where the page scrollbar would normally be (far right side of the page).  Is this possible with css?

I've tried playing with the `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo element but the only properties that seem to work for that are for size, and color.  None of the positioning properties I've tried are being applied (margin, padding, position etc).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be directly possible with CSS.

One amateur way that I could think of is,

- creating a parent div that spans the entire width of the page.
- Inside this parent div, create two child divs: one for your content (with ⁠ `overflow-y: scroll` ⁠) and another div that takes up the remaining space on the right.

This way, the scrollbar will appear to be on the far right side of the page, while it is actually attached to the content div.

An example snippet

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fake-scrollbar {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #a1a1a1; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
       <!-- Your (left side) content here -->
    </div>

    <div class="fake-scrollbar"></div>
 </div>
```

⁠

Upon following this, one thing you should be mindful is the *responsiveness of the website*.